# Is there a way to make a GIF animation not just suddenly revert when using :hover classes in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div element in my HTML, I have set the background-image property to a still image but used the :hover class to change the background-image property to an animated GIF, this works fine for my purposes but when the user leaves the element (stops hovering) the GIF stops and is immediately replaced by the still image, looking a bit displeasing.

I assume this would require JavaScript or jQuery to handle which I'm fine with but if there is any other easier ways that can be implemented into the CSS itself that would be great.

Thanks

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxt5ktc1/

my example itself: drawdeloop.co.uk

```
header .headerButtonNav {
background-image: url('../Images/Icons/ringUnglow100100.png');
background-size: cover;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
top: 60px;
}
header .headerButtonNav:hover {
background-image: url('../Images/Resources/circleCrossButton400400.gif');
}
```

Comment: there are no images shown in your fiddle

Comment: I'm aware, it's just to show the context. The site I'm working on with this issue is also linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a transition to your `.headerButtonNav` to make it feel more 'smooth'.

I've updated your Fiddle to see what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/nxt5ktc1/1/

Comment: That's absolutely beautiful, It's certainly not how I was expecting this to be handled but it works and that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CSS transition property? 
For example:

```
-webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try insert images in html code and hidden their (display: none), that would they can loading before